# Using Swift DataFrame as source for SwiftUI Table

Tags: swift, dataframe, swiftui

Does anybody have experience with displaying data from a Swift TabularData Dataframe in a SwiftUI Table? Using V and HStacks works but it would be nice to be able to use the Table features, however I struggle with error due to lack of conformity to TableColumnContent protocol. All forms of `Static method an error 'buildBlock' requires that 'ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, EmptyView>' conform to 'TableColumnContent'` errors.

Any advise?

Here is some playground code (not including random .csv file):

```
import TabularData
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

var table: DataFrame

var filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/SampleTable4.csv")
var dataTable: DataFrame
do{
    dataTable = try DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: filePath)
} catch {
    dataTable = DataFrame()
}

let numOfrows = dataTable.shape.rows
let numOfcols = dataTable.shape.columns


struct tableView: View {
    var body: some View {
//////this works
        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<numOfrows){currRow in
                HStack{
                ForEach(0..<numOfcols){currCol in
                    
                        let datapoint = "\(dataTable[row: currRow][currCol])" //sloppy coercion
                        Text("\(datapoint)") 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
///this does not as have no idea how to without re-inventing the wheel.
///Hoping for some elegant way..
        HStack{
            Table(dataTable.Rows){
                ForEach(0..<numOfcols){currCol in
                    //parse some UI Table column out of DataFrame column
                }
        }
    }
//
let view = tableView()
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(view)
```

Comment: `Table` takes an array of a struct with values and displays them in a table view. `TabularData` is a set of datapoints arranged in rows and columns. You are trying to force data that is already arranged in rows and columns into a UI structure whose sole purpose is arranging data into rows and columns and then displaying it. It is a bit nonsensical. You are much better off decoding your CSV file into an array of struct, and then you can use a `Table` or a `LazyGrid`

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I see your point. However, I would like to use the DataFrame features (join, merge on etc) which I would have to implement manually if I were to use an array.